# Send two parametres from android client to WCF WS

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf

I am trying to develop a project in which my android application sends a IP-address and port-number to a wcf Web Service:
But I can't do it
and it is possible to have the response of the web service???
IService.cs

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Connection/{ipadress}/{port}")]
    bool Connection(string ipadress,string port);
```

Service.svc.cs

```
    public bool Connection(string ipadress, string port)
    {
        /*          */
            return true;

    }
```

Code Android

```
    public boolean Connection_Net() {
    String url_service = "http://algotimesheet.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc/Connection/ipadress/port";
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    URL url;

    try {
        url = new URL(url_service);
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
        urlConnection.connect();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("ipadress","192.168.1.1");
        jsonObject.put("port","4370");
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        outputStreamWriter.write(jsonObject.toString());
        outputStreamWriter.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't need any json object, just make a "GET" request  like `http://algotimesheet.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc/Connection/192.168.1.1/4370` (unlike you try to "POST" )

Comment: and how the request will be sent?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1S02pbe

Answer (score -1):

If you send a JSON you need to write the service to expect an object and use `POST`

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    UriTemplate = "Connection")]
bool Connection(Data data);

public bool Connection(Data data)
{
    /*          */
        return true;

}
```

And design the object like this:

```
public class Data()
{
    public string ip {get; set;}
    public string port{get;set;}
}
```

If you want to make a `GET` you just need to add the values to the `URL`

Comment: I want to make a `GET` but my solution does not work

Comment: after  `urlConnection.connect();` what I must do to send data?

Comment: @AbdAlah Try just adding the values to the URL and then do the `urlConnection.connect();`, I don't think that you need to do anything else